# Javascript buttons not working

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to create a button in javascript that when clicked adds an item to a basket

heres my code

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
var prices = new Array (100,50);
var sizes = new Array ("450*350","100*50");

function load()
{
if(displayProductInfo==true)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
    {
        $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="'+imgSrc[i]+'" width="525px" height="350px"/></li>');
        $('#products ul').append('<li>Price: £' + prices[i] +'</li>');
        $('#products ul').append('<li>Size: ' + sizes[i] +'</li>');
        $('#products ul').append('<button type="button" onclick="addToBasket(i)">Add To Basket</button>');
    }
}
}

function addToBasket(itemAdded)
{
    alert("clicked")
}
```

Everything works fine, except when a button is clicked it doesn't seem to run function addToBasket

whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't just call `addToBasket(i)`, because `i` in the scope of that function, doesn't exist.  You should change it to `$('#products ul').append('<button type="button" onclick="addToBasket(' + i + ')">Add To Basket</button>');`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `new Array(...)` - `[...]` is enough.

doing `$('#products ul')` more than once is bad. you do it 4 times in a single iteration. store it in a variable and reuse it: `var list = $('#products ul');`

and the reason why it probably fails - as the others wrote - you don't pass the value of `i` but instead try to read `i` when you click the button.

```
var imgSrc = ["images/hangings/1.jpg", "images/hangings/2.jpg"],
    prices = [100, 50],
    sizes = ["450*350", "100*50"];

function load() {
    if (displayProductInfo) {
        var list = $('#products ul');
        for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            list.append('<li><img src="' + imgSrc[i] + '" width="525px" height="350px"/></li>');
            list.append('<li>Price: £' + prices[i] + '</li>');
            list.append('<li>Size: ' + sizes[i] + '</li>');
            list.append('<li><button type="button" onclick="addToBasket(' + i + ')">Add To Basket</button></li>');
        }
    }
}

function addToBasket(itemAdded) {
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
var prices = new Array (100,50);
var sizes = new Array ("450*350","100*50");

function load()
{
if(displayProductInfo==true)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
    {
        $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="'+imgSrc[i]+'" width="525px" height="350px"/></li>');
        $('#products ul').append('<li>Price: £' + prices[i] +'</li>');
        $('#products ul').append('<li>Size: ' + sizes[i] +'</li>');
        $('#products ul').append($('<button />', {'data-item': i}).text('Add To Basket').click(addToBasket));
    }
}
}

function addToBasket()
{
    alert("clicked on " + $(this).attr('data-item'));
}


var displayProductInfo = true;
load();
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/ZGNCg/).